# Are these UML Secondory actors mandatory?

Tags: c#, .net, use-case, uml

I have an issue while creating UML diagram wrt secondary actors.

Issue is in confusion in use of secondary actor.

Use case is for a website and its for account creation.

Usually account is created by Admin ...so use case can be written like

Admin -> Create account <- secondary actor?

but i need to put secondary actor on the right hand side my question is it mandatory?

if yes .. wht to put there?

Answer (score 3):

> All use  case should have a **Primary
>   Actor**. ( The one who use sytstem to
>   achieve a goal)

and

> Use cases may not have
>   Secondary(Supporting) actors. **Secondary(Supporting) actors are
>   not mandatory.**

and

> It is a convention to put primary
>   actors on the left side and secondary
>   on the right side. . You do not have
>   to follow this convention. But this
>   Just make diagram more clear

[image]